# Angularjs getting input values with in div

Tags: angularjs

In a div I have declared all input values but need to get the input values but I don't know how to get please help me my div code is. I need to get the Project Name,Project Status,Project Startdate,Project Enddate but I have used

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="addmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Add Project Details</h4>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
          <div class="form-group">

            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjname" id="prjname" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjname" required />
                <span ng-show="form.firstName.$dirty && form.firstName.$error.required" class="help-block">First name is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Client Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div ng-controller="MyCntrl" >
                    <select class="form-control" ng-model="myColor" ng-change="change(myColor)" >
                        <option value="">Select Client Name</option>                                
                        <option ng-repeat="color in colors" 
                                value="{{color.value}}" 
                                ng-selected="{{color.value == myColor}}">
                          {{color.clientname}}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Status</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjsta" id="prjsta" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.prjsta" required />
                <span ng-show="form.username.$dirty && form.username.$error.required" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Startdate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">

            <!--   <input type="text" name="prjstartdate" id="prjstartdate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjstartdate" required />-->
<div class="container" id="sandbox-container">
 <div class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
 <input class="input-sm form-control" name="start" type="text">

    </div>

</div>
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>


            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project Enddate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjenddate" id="prjenddate" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjenddate" required />
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Project PIN Url</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input type="text" name="prjurl" id="prjurl" class="form-control" ng-model="vm.user.prjurl" required />
                <span ng-show="form.password.$dirty && form.password.$error.required" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem and where did the data come from? Maybe post your controller too?

Comment: @kdlcruz i need the Project Name input value

Comment: I'm guessing you need a data binding? If now, please be specific. see this https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04

Comment: @kdlcruz no Project Name is input filed what ever user entered value i need to send to db so i want user entered vale

Answer (score 0):

Your question is hard to understand.
If you want to get the values of Project Name, Project Status, Project Startdate and Project Enddate. It should be available in $scope.vm because all your ngModel values have 'vm.' in them.
Project Name - $scope.vm.prjname
Project Status - $scope.vm.prjsta
Project Startdate - $scope.vm.user.prjstartdate
Project Enddate - $scope.vm.user.prjenddate

Comment: if i want individual how can i get

Comment: yes u r correct all the values is storing in  $scope.vm if want to get individual  how can i pls suggest me

Answer (score 0):

If I could understand the your question, then you want to bind the value of input so that when it changes you can send it to DB. To do so, you need to add watcher on the scope.

Since you have not posted angular code, I created my own to understand. You will observe the values of input in console that how they have been watched by controller.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.prjname = '';

    $scope.$watch(function() {
       return $scope.prjname;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log("change detected: " + newValue)
    });
 }
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    <input type="text" name="prjname" id="prjname" class="form-control" ng-model="prjname" ng-change="getValue(this.value)" required />   
</div>
```

You can see in it working in fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/anandgh/x0y901ym/

Hope this helps to you. Happy coding!